# How to pass node name to ssh through pipe in linux command line?

Tags: linux, ssh, pipe, xargs

There are several jobs in nodes and want to see my job is running there. Due to the memory problem, the node is occupied by me(user) as sleep (just took the node without actual job) and qstat shows running status but actually no job is running. I need to check using ssh.

**qstat** shows as follows

- job-ID  prior   name       user         state submit/start at     queue                          slots ja-task-ID
- 3508392 0.60500 joonho0    joonho       **r**     04/09/2020 12:17:03 **skylake@node02**                    36
- 3508393 0.60500 joonho1    joonho       **r**     04/09/2020 12:17:03 **skylake@node22**                    36
- 3509074 0.00000 amplong16  joonho       qw    04/09/2020 13:22:20                                   36

In my trial,

- qstat | awk '/@/ {print $8}' | cut -d@ -f2

print

- node02
- node22

I want to pass these to ssh through pipe then I can use

- ssh **node02** ps aux | grep amp_run.py

where I can check the job "amp_run.py" is running.

But the following fails,

- qstat | awk '/@/ {print $8}' | cut -d@ -f2 | xargs ssh  ps aux | grep amp_run.py

Is there a way to do this in a command line, rather than making a script? Or any other suggestion to check the running jobs in the occupied nodes rather than all nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a simple xargs usage.
When the arguments which come from pipe locates any place in the next command,
-I{} locates the place. So the command should be lime this.

- qstat | awk '/@/ {print $8}' | cut -d@ -f2 | xargs -I{} ssh {} ps aux | grep amp_run.py